# How to draw UILabel Into Context

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm trying to draw a UIlabel into a new Context, at a specific location.  I know you can draw just the NSString into a context easily, but I want to retain the text size, color, and word wrap style of the UILabel.  Thanks for your help!

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);   

 // here is where I want to draw UILabel to context

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw *any* view [using `-renderInContext:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788662/rendering-uiview-with-its-children-iphone-sdk), but if all you need is just retain the text size, color and word wrap style, you could simply [use `-drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:) to customize all options.

```
[label.textColor set];
[label.text drawInRect:label.bounds
              withFont:label.font
         lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode
             alignment:label.textAlignment];
```

There is also [a `-drawTextInRect:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILabel/drawTextInRect:) in UILabel, but Apple says *"You should not call this method directly."*

Comment: Awesome answer, I gave it a shot and it worked great, except that it is drawing at the top of the context ( top of the screen) as apposed to the bottom where the UILabel actually is. any thoughts? thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Fierce: Change `label.bounds` to any CGRect you like.

Comment: I know this is a long time ago but I've been trying to find an answer like this for a long time. Do you know how to create this effect in Swift? I've been trying to translate it but can't figure it out.

Comment: @frank21: `-drawInRect:withFont:...` has been deprecated, but you could use `drawInRect(_, withAttributes:_)` instead.

Comment: Should I also add the linebreakmode and alignment as attributes?

Comment: @frank21: If your UILabel doesn't use the default values, yes. Also you may need to add the shadowColor attributes as well.